# What am I doing wrong - can't instantiate object from Main (Custom class)

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

Hands up, I'm struggling with a programming question for M257 at OU, its formative and carries no marks and is due in a few days. I can't call the constructor from the test class and have struggled for several hours to no avail, the class compiles in Netbeans 6.91 fine but the constructor won't create the object. What am I doing wrong?

I had no problem with first question but am totally stuck here, obviously missing something significant - guidance please. The idea is to pass in the name of the file to the class, I can do the rest once I know the file is open and scanner initialised.

```
===============
/**
 * Title: WordCounter class
 * Description: M257 TMA01, Q2 - word counter class as described in instructions
 * @author Andrew Broxholme
 */

package tma01q2;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class WordCounter
{  
    //Class instance variables
    public static int totalWords;
    public static int totalEven;
    public static int totalOdd;
    public static int totalLetters;

    private Scanner fileScanner;
    String sourceFile;
    String line;    //The lines of the text file

    //Single argument constructor, accepts source filename
    public boolean WordCounter(String fileToRead)
    {
        sourceFile = fileToRead;
        try
        {
            openRead();
            while (fileScanner.hasNext())
            {
                // Process each line of the text file
                line = fileScanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);
       //         countWords();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            fileScanner.close();
        }
    }

    //openRead, opens the file and processes each line of the file until finished
    private boolean openRead() throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            fileScanner = new Scanner(sourceFile);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            return false;
        }
    } 
    // More methods to be added   
}

/*
 * TestWordCounter.
 * Description: Tests the WordCounter class as per TMA01q2 instructions
 * @author Andrew Broxholme
 * V1.0 30th April 2011
 */

package tma01q2;

public class TestWordCounter
{
   //Create a WordCounter to process the specified text file.
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String testFile = "haiku.txt";
      WordCounter fileStats = new WordCounter(testFile);
   }
}
```

When I try to comiple this is what it passes back.

```
Compiling 1 source file to C:\M257\TMA01\TMA01Q2\build\classes
C:\M257\TMA01\TMA01Q2\src\tma01q2\TestWordCounter.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor WordCounter(java.lang.String)
location: class tma01q2.WordCounter
      WordCounter fileStats = new WordCounter(testFile);
1 error
C:\M257\TMA01\TMA01Q2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:246: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\M257\TMA01\TMA01Q2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:113: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I haven't given up on this and will update question if I find the answer first.

8th May 2011: The answers were helpful but in the end although in the end I gave up on this question as the further I got I realised I just didn't know enough about how subclasses inherit from superclasses and need to try some simpler (and to me more meaningful) examples to deepen my understanding. The problem though was that NetBeans is too good at suggesting what you need without telling you exactly why its doing what it is doing, fine if your an experienced java developer, but not so good if your starting out.

I'm already started (i.e read the brief) for TMA02 and will give myself a full two months, much more sensible one thinks!

Comment: "The problem though was that NetBeans is too good at suggesting what you need without telling you exactly why its doing what it is doing, fine if your an experienced java developer, but not so good if your starting out."  +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a constructor. Remove the `boolean` as return type - constructors don't have return types. So:

```
public WordCounter(String fileToRead)
```

instead of

```
public boolean WordCounter(String fileToRead)
```

And that's what the error tells you - the compiler cannot find a constructor with that name.

See: [constructors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: Ok thanks, that is helpful. The instructions ask me to return a true/ false if the file opens then true/ false when processing is complete, I'll do that with instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

the signature of the constructor is wrong.

```
public WordCounter(String fileToRead)
{
     sourceFile = fileToRead;
     try
      {
            openRead();
            while (fileScanner.hasNext())
            {
                // Process each line of the text file
                line = fileScanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);
       //         countWords();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            fileScanner.close();
        }
    }
```

use constructor like this. Replace the signature of constructor to

```
public WordCounter(String fileToRead)
```